# Vectorization of matrix multiplication with scalar (Scalar is value of other matrix at index i)

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I can't seem wrap my head on vectorizing a for loop in my MATLAB code.  Basically, I have this code:

```
% Let that:
%Tp = scalar
%N, = scalar (Say 1000)
%Ac, = 4x4 matrix
%pre = 1x4 matrix
%post = 4x2 matrix
%wy1 = N+1x1 matrix (so it would be 1001*1)
%wy2 = N+1x1 matrix (so it would be 1001*1)

% preallocate
delta_ksi=Tp/N;
AcT =Ac';
sum_matrix=zeros(4,1);
Fl=zeros(4,1);

% calculate the sum
for i=1:N
 Fl=delta_ksi*expm(AcT*delta_ksi*i)*post*[wy1(1,i); wy2(1,i);];
 sum_matrix= sum_matrix+Fl;
end

 %value I need
delta_f_des_ff= pre*sum_matrix;
```

What I have in mind is to construct a 3D matrix Fl_3D (4 x 1x 1000) and then do array multiplication with `i = 1:1000`, but I kept getting incompatible dimension error when multiplying with `[wy1(1,i); wy2(1,i)]` which also use the index `i`.

Any clue on what is the best approach to do this? Is vectorization still possible?
Thanks!

Edit:

Background:
I am trying to troubleshoot a bottleneck code in a Simulink project.
Code Profiling shows that the above function hogging most of the runtime.

I am hoping vectorizing could solve the performance issue. I also just found out the bottleneck comes from expm() operation. Any suggestion to improve this is also welcomed!

Comment: The dimensions of `wy1` and `wy2` don't seem to match... if `post` is 4x4 then `[wy1(); wy2()]` should have 4 rows, right? Also, why the extra elements in `wy1` and `wy2` that are never used (`i` only goes up to `N`)?

Comment: Ah my bad, `post` is 4x2, not 4x4. :/ which extra element are you referring to? `[wy1(); wy2()]` is 2x1 and the elements are non-zero

Comment: Dimensions and vectorization aside, do you really mean to take the [Matrix Exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) (`expm`) of the argument versus just taking the exponential (`exp`) of the argument?

Comment: yeah it's `expm` for my case.

Comment: Cool.  I've seen some confused in the past; glad you're not one.

Comment: Can you diagonalize Ac ? That would make the exponentiation easy to vectorize.

Comment: @percusse Hmm Ac itself is not a constant matrix, I imagine adding diagonalization operation are just going to add the overhead, no?

Comment: No then you can use scalar exponentiation and vectorize the i dependent terms. So instead of a loop you perform a big matrix multiplication

Comment: Could you perhaps give a sort of working minimum example to that approach? How do you suggest diagonalizing an existing data stream of Ac? thanks